# log(OPT) approximation for directed balanced vertex separator

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms

[Leighton, Rao](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=331526) presented an $O(\log n)$ approximation algorithm for directed and undirected balanced vertex separator. [Agarwal, Charikar, Makarychev, Makarychev](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1060590.1060675&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=28694540&CFTOKEN=81623558) improved this approximation factor of directed balanced vertex separator to $O(\sqrt{\log n})$.

Is there an $O(\log \mathsf{opt})$ approximation algorithm for directed balanced vertex separator, where $\mathsf{opt}$ is the optimal size of the directed balanced vertex separator ?

I would appreciate any references/pointers.